# Windows Phone 7 collapsible list

Tags: android, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am new to WP7, so please be gentle!

What is the best practice for displaying long lists (~50 items) in WP7 without taking up loads of vertical space?  In android, I would just use a spinner, but I do not see anything similar in WP7.

Do I just create a clickable label that displays a new page with a populated `<ListBox />` control in it?

I want to be able to plot the contents of a specific file onto a `<Map />` control, with the file list taking up at little room as possible until needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the ListBox control:

http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/

EDIT:

Oh I see, you're trying to create a picker control. In this case take a look at the Silverlight toolkit: silverlight.codeplex.com and specifically the ListPicker control within that toolkit.

Comment: Hello, I started off with a ListBox control, but I do not seem able to collapse it, which is my problem.  Am I missing something stupid here?

Comment: Oh I see, you're trying to create a picker control. In this case take a look at the Silverlight toolkit: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/ and specifically the ListPicker control within that toolkit.

Comment: Perfect.  I downloaded that last night and forgot about it.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Steve - Just for admin, would you be OK with adding the ListPicker comment as an answer which I could mark as correct?  I would do it myself but I guess you will lose the prestige..